# python script that takes command line arguments needs to be called from another python script

Tags: python, scripting, python-3.6

I completely understand that I should have written the script right the first time, but the fact is I have a script that generates a data file based upon two values passed to it from the command line- like this:

```
 [sinux1~]: ./sim_gen.py 100 .3
```

I need to call this script from within another script, iterating over a range of values. I searched around and after navigating through all of the "you shouldn't," I tried :

```
 exec(open("./sim_gen.py 100 .3").read())
```

And this doesn't seem to work.
Help?

Comment: `print(subprocess.Popen(["python","./sim_gen.py",100,0.3]).communicate())`

Comment: @JoranBeasley You probably want `sys.executable` rather than `python` (and if not, you probably want to trust the shbang instead). Also, the arguments have to be strings. Also, why construct a `Popen` to `communicate` with instead of just using `run` (or, for older Python, `check_output` or similar)?

Comment: all valid points ... just because ive been doing this since before `check_output` ... so its sort of force of habit :P but you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this down into pieces:

```
exec(open("./sim_gen.py 100 .3").read())
```

This is equivalent to:

```
f = open("./sim_gen.py 100 .3")
contents = f.read()
exec(contents)
```

That `open` is the same `open` you use for, say, reading a text file or a CSV. You're asking for a file named `"sim_gen.py 100 .3"` in the current directory. Do you have one? Of course not. So the `open` fails.

---

The best solution is, as you already know, to rewrite `sim_gen.py` so that you can `import` it and call a function and pass the arguments to it.

---

Failing that, the cleanest answer is probably to just [run the Python script as a subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module):

```
import subprocess
import sys
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "./sim_gen.py", "100", ".3"])
```

Notice that this is effectively the same thing you're doing when you run the script from your shell, so if it was OK there, it's almost surely OK here.

---

If you really need to `exec` for some reason, you will need to do something really hacky, and temporarily change [`argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) for that script's code:

```
import sys
_argv = sys.argv
try:
    sys.argv = ["./sim_gen.py", "100", ".3"]
    with open("./sim_gen.py 100 .3"):
        exec(f.read())
finally:
    sys.argv = _argv
```

Although really, unless the point of running this is to silently modify your own module's globals or the like, you (a) almost certainly don't really need `exec`, and (b) want to pass an explicit `globals` argument even if you do really need it.

Comment: Not only does this work perfectly, but you explained it extremely well. Thank you. This code only really needed to run once. I plan to go back amd refactor, write it correctly anyways. Thank you.